# Migrating from Java 6 to Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, java-6, migrate

I have some projects in Java 6 and Spring on app server. Because of limitations in my infrastructure and governance planninng I cannot migrate to newer Java 7 or 8.

I think i could add Kotlin in those projects to use features like functional programming.

It this approach a good way to go?

Thanks

Comment: It would really help to know more about your "limitations". In general, I'd say give Kotlin a try. Better stay away from `lambdaj` (suggested in one of the answers) - IMHO, it's really ugly (and outdated). If Kotlin doesn't work for you there are still better alternatives, e.g. [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) and either [streamsupport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) or [LWS](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion Kotlin is a great language because it addresses all the pain points from Java in terms of boiler plate code and adds all of this plus functional programming to Java 6 (your target Java version)

So go ahead and give it a try.
If you use IntelliJ you can convert Java files to Kotlin and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

For kotlin, I don't know. But I think there is a lambda library, developed by Mario Fusco, an italian "Java Champion" (the only italian Java champion as far as I know), which is named lambdaj.
I google it for you and I found [this](https://github.com/mariofusco/lambdaj). I suggest you to google it a bit more, I remember that long time ago it was available in a jar for ant build.

I hope it helps.